# Pullquote Block Styles disappeared?

Tags: block-editor

Did the Pullquote block styles disappear in the editor?

There used to be a **Styles** section in the sidebar panel with the "Default" and "Solid Color" options, as it is written in the [documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/pullquote-block/):

[image: pullquote block styles]

But in wordpress 6.0.2 it does not seem to show up anymore.

Comment: this area of the UI is under active development, you might find the styles are there but shown in a different way. In this case it appears that styles are no longer necessary as you can get a solid colour pull quote by disabling borders and adding a background colour, and that many other variations are possible that weren't when it was just the preset styles, so the defaults may have been removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solid colour pullquote style had been deprecated and removed in 2021, and was removed in favor of more comprehensive options based on block style options:

> Given that we can now achieve border and background variations using block supports, we're removing the existing styles and adding a textAlign attribute to compensate.

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/30951

If you really wanted, you could try to bring it back via a block variation or block style using code, but it would be a brand new style or variation, not the old style switched back on.

For future reference, testing with the Gutenberg plugin can help avoid these things being surprises.

---

> as it is written in the documentation:

Both yes and no, some parts of that article show the newer interface, but there is indeed a mention of it in text further below.

WordPress.org is not an infallible perfectly up to date documentation source, although it is the closest we have. It's likely to be one of the following:

- someone updated the article but didn't notice the reference further down ( most likely )
- something was kept behind for users still on older versions of WordPress ( less likely)

You should file a report on the .org meta Trac that there is a bug/inconsistency in the documentation for that page, and an out of date screenshot, including links.

Comment: I was not able to find the github link. TKS
I will make a comment on the doc page.
I will declare the old styles in the theme.json. An old theme I made relies on this choice.

Comment: WP docs aren't managed on github

Answer (score 1):

I still have it in 6.0.2.

- Color (text, bg)
- Typography (size, appearance)
- Border (color, radius, width)
- Advanced

Maybe your theme or a new plugin update is removing them?

Comment: Marc isn't asking about those options, but rather the preset styles shown in the styles panel

Comment: Yes, Tom is right, I was asking about the Default-Solid color option, but thanks for the answer